# updatedb & locate command problem - Files from external hard drive are no longer indexed after rebooting

Tags: command-line, updatedb, locate

Files from my external hard drive are no longer indexed after rebooting.  I have to remount and then run

```
# updatedb
```

after each reboot.  The problem is updatedb takes a few minutes for my external hard drives.  Is there any way I can retain indexing for my externals after I reboot so that the locate command can search through my externals?

**EDIT:  Per Request here are my specs:**

```
$ cat /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"

# mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/me/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=me)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/me type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sdd1 on /media/Little Boy type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sde1 on /media/Fat Man type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)

# on_ac_power; echo $?
255
```

Comment: Please provide the config files and mount options: `cat /etc/updatedb.conf`, `mount`, `on_ac_power; echo $?`

Comment: will do, won't have access to a linux machine for about 8 more hours

Comment: Arrange, I've updated my answer with my specs, thanks for your help =)

Comment: <note for the future>Here's how to GENERALLY figure out what `updatedb` is doing: (1.) Run `updatedb` with `--verbose` and `--debug-pruning`. (2.) Look at the text to see what is being indexed and not being indexed --> adjust your `/etc/updatedb.conf`. I `grep`d for files that I needed but were being skipped. For example I had modify `/etc/updatedb.conf` with: (1.) `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "no"` (2.) remove `nfs nfs4 nfsd autofs` from `PRUNEFS` (3.) remove `/net` from `PRUNEPATHS`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Files from your external harddisk are not indexed because `updatedb` is configured to not index anything under `/media`, which is where external storage is usually mounted. This configuration is set in the file `/etc/updatedb.conf`. Specifically the entry `/media` in the `PRUNEPATHS` line.

Some ideas how you can make `updatedb` to index your external drive:

## 1. Mount the external drive unter `/mnt`.

If your external harddisk is supposed to be **mounted permanently** then I suggest to configure it so that it is mounted under `/mnt` instead of under `/media`. That can usually be done by editing `/etc/fstab`. Search for "fstab" to learn about that. You will need sudo rights to edit `/etc/fstab`.

## 2. Create a dedicated database for your external harddisk and query that on demand.

The following command will create a dedicated database:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/externalharddisk
```

This will create the database in the hidden file `.externalharddisk.db` in your home. You do not need `sudo` for that command. Execute the same command again to keep the database updated. Carefull: if you run that command while the external harddisk is not mounted then `updatedb` will think the files are deleted and will empty the database.

You can set up a script to automate that task. Search for "cronjob" to learn how to do that. Note: you can set up a user cronjob as user. You do not need sudo rights to set up a user cronjob.

The following command will query the database:

```
locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db searchterm
```

You can also query the dedicated database and the default database at the same time:

```
locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db: searchterm
```

The colon at the end followed by nothing means to also search in the default database.

You can make an alias for easier use. Put the following line in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias locate-external='locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db:'
```

Now you can use `locate` to search only the default database and `locate-external` to also search in your external harddisk.

## 3. Remove `/media` from `PRUNEPATHS`

**Note: I do not recommend this**! This is because of the way `updatedb` works. If `updatedb` runs while the external harddisk is removed then all entries pointing to the external harddisk will be removed from the database. If `updatedb` runs while the external harddisk is connected then entries pointing to the external harddisk will be added again. Since `updatedb` is running regulary in the background you can never be sure whether the files from the external harddisk are currently indexed or not.

Furthermore: if you remove `/media` from `PRUNEPATHS`, this behaviour will also apply to any other external storage you happen to have mounted while `updatedb` is updating the database.

Comment: You can additionally add this alias to your `~/.bashrc` file: `alias updatedb-external='sudo updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/externalharddisk'`

Comment: +1 to both you and OP. However rather than a separate external DB command ie `locate-external`, I'm considering appending three databases into one with `--database /mnt/c...` for WSL, `--dataabase /mnt/e...` for WSL+Linux shared scripts & documents and `--database /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` for dual-booted Ubuntu 16.04. ie All three databases on the same locate command line (with an alias of course). But before I start it would be nice to know if it will work. Can I get your thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't agree with the argument of removing `/media` from `PRUNEPATHS`. While yes it has the problem you mentioned, excluding it entirely is even worse - you will NEVER locate files on those drives. It's like amputating your fingers so they don't get burnt while cooking (unless there's another obvious solution that is implied which I'm not seeing).

Comment: great advice! I think I'll just mount everything in /mnt. Quick question: Is there anything wrong with mounting all my drives at linux startup (including ntfs / windows drive).. does it slow down my linux os in any way or anything else I should be aware off?

Answer (score 2):

In `updatedb.conf` you have `/media` in `PRUNEPATHS`. You should remove it, since your external drives seem to be mounted there.

Answer (score 2):

These are further embellishments to be added to **Lesmana's answer**

[1] slight embellishment: may i suggest adding the -i to ***make sure case of the query searched is no longer an issue***: so to add to .bashrc >>

alias locate-external='locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db: **-i**'

[2] As regards the ***updating of both databases***; the one in the main HD and the new one in the external; it is probably worth adding one more entry to the .bashrc

alias updateALL='sudo updatedb && updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/externalharddisk'

and then to simply run `updateALL` in terminal to update both databases at once

*PS:of course do not forget to run `. ~/.bashrc` to firm it all up once a new line is saved in the .bashrc*
*PS²: and of course too `externalharddisk` in all the lines above is replaced by the name of your external HD name ie /media/YOURHDNAME*

*PS³  and you can of course conflate both update and locate in your .bashrc

alias LO='sudo updatedb && updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/externalharddisk ; locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db: **-i**'

so now all you need to update and search is to enter   LO 'followed by the terms you seek'

Comment: +1 for sequencing update and then locate