# How do I tell locate to keep the index of an external HDD?

Tags: external-hdd, updatedb

I changed my configuration so locate is also searching through external harddisks that are mounted in `/media`.

My `/etc/updatedb.conf`:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /home/.ecryptfs /media/Win8"
PRUNEFS=...(rest is default)
```

my main HDD i always use is

```
/media/rubo77/Data
```

if it is connected, and I run `updatedb` it is indexed, but each time I atart my computer with detached HDD the dayly `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` is clearing that up.

I would like to be able to find files on the detached device too. If I don't want to I can always use `locate -e` that only shows currently existing files.

How can I tell locate to keep the index for files in media if the drive is not mounted so I can locate files on the detached device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you have multiple options here:

1. Clearly the best way to do exactly what you want would be to **tell cron to wait until the drive is mounted** before updating the database. I imagine someone much more familiar with cron and/or bash then I am could tell you how.
2. What you could definitely do, although it isn't exactly what you want, is to **create a new database just for the removable drive**. See [this closely related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60202/updatedb-locate-command-problem-files-from-external-hard-drive-are-no-longer) for detailed instructions on how to do that. Then you can just have to manually update the database when the drive is mounted.
3. **If the contents of the drive don't change often**, there are a lot of alternatives. For me, I have many different external drives so for each one I will often pipe a command like `ls -RD1` to a **text file**, and then I can just use grep and other tools whenever I want.

Comment: Nice workarounds, But still the best solution would be a "keep" flag for locate or such. Maybe I should make a feature request to the developers

Comment: This solves it for me: I add these aliases in `~/.bashrc file`:  `alias updatedb-external='sudo updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/externalharddisk'` and `alias locate-external='locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db:'`