# Is there a way of indexing contents of external drives that are sometimes disconnected?

Tags: usb, indexing

I own almost a dozen of USB drives and hard disks that I only plug in when I need them. Because they are so many, I often find myself in the situation of having to connect each and every of the devices in order to find the file that I am looking for.

What I think would be a good solution for me would be a file search engine which would index the names of all the files in these drives and tells me the brand and model names of the drive it is stored on. This indexation would run each time I connect a drive.

Does such a tool exist ? Are there other ways to solve this problem ?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/60202/updatedb-locate-command-problem-files-from-external-hard-drive-are-no-longer

Comment: I would run tree command on each redirecting output to a meaningful name like TOSHIBA 140 GB SATA I 5400 RPM.text. Store them all in one directory and use write to open all files in directory and then do 'Ctrl'+'F' to find a name.