# locate command doesn't locate files in /media folder

Tags: command-line, locate, updatedb

I know there is a file in `/media` folder, then I searched with `locate` command, but it doesn't locate the file. I did `sudo updatedb`, then `locate` command again, but it doesn't locate the file.

I suspect `locate` path environment parameter since `/media` folder filesystem is on a seperate hard disk from the main stuff.

Should I edit locate path environment parameter?? How do I do it? or Am I missing more??

Comment: Well, what command did you do ? `locate filename`?

Comment: yes. locate filename. locate directory name. locate whatever. I tried many things since there wasn't any success.

Comment: do a `sudo updatedb` before the `locate` command so local file records get updated!

Comment: @George OP stated in the question they did that :/

Comment: @Smile take a look at this one : https://askubuntu.com/q/60202/295286  Let us know if that helps

Comment: My mistake especially when the format is a bit off @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: If the other question doesn't help, please [edit] your question explaining what you've tried and we will reopen it

Comment: I followed the link and confirmed there is PRUNEPATHS = /media with other folder names in /etc/updatedb.conf file. I also did "sudo updatedb" again. Then "locate blueprints.txt", "sudo locate blueprints.txt", "locate /media/blueprints.txt" "locate whatever" really. I did all combinations. I'm tired of this "locate" command. I'll probably just use "find" command. I just wanted to be proficient. Maybe next time I'll find out what caused this issue. Thanks guys really. I'll keep studying. Have a nice day:)